# How to remove gap between components using Grid Layout in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

Using grid layout I am creating composites. But I am unable to reduce gap between two composites. Please see the image and code. Could anyone help me in this

[image]

```
parent.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL,GridData.CENTER, true, false, 3, 1));// whole group
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(3, false);

        recurrenceGroup.setLayout(gridLayout);

        radioButton1 = new Button(parent.getContent(), SWT.RADIO);
        radioButton1.setText("Radio 1");
        GridData gridData = GridDataFactory.fillDefaults().span(3, 1).align(SWT.FILL, SWT.BEGINNING).grab(true, false).create();
        radioButton1.setLayoutData(gridData);
        radioButton2 = new Button(parent.getContent(), SWT.RADIO);
        radioButton2.setText("Radio 2");       
        textBox = new Text(parent.getContent(), SWT.BORDER);
        textBox.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINING, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
        secsLabel = new Label(parent.getContent(), SWT.NONE);
        secsLabel.setText("secs");
```

Comment: What is `parent.getContent()`? What layout is set on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GridLayout#horizontalSpacing` and `GridLayout#verticalSpacing` respectively to change the spacing between children:

With horizontal spacing:

[image]

Without horizontal spacing:

[image]

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3, false);
    layout.horizontalSpacing = 0;
    shell.setLayout(layout);

    for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        new Label(shell, SWT.NONE).setText("Label: " + i);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: These `horizontalSpacing`, `horizontalSpacing`  are no longer there!

Comment: @TiMr which version of SWT are you using? I can still see them

Comment: @MiMr They are clearly still there, even in the [latest release of SWT](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridLayout.html).